# Creat an edit form for each model in an IEnumerable<model> ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create an edit form for each model in an `IEnumerable` of models. Basically, my Index.cshtml page has a table of every object from my database table and I want to add an edit form for each model. However, for whatever reason whenever I post an individual form, the data all gets passed as NULL.

Here is what I have:

Model:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.ASNGFellows.ToListAsync());
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        #update database object
    }

    return View(Person)
}
```

View (Index.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
            </th>
            <th class="actionItemsTh">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div>
                    <form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.id)
                        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.name)
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.name)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.name)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The form generates properly and when I submit, it hits the controller method, however the `person` object has null values. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your form like following.

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <input type="hidden" name="person.id" value="@item.id"/>
      @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.name)
      <input type="text" name="person.name" value="@item.name" />
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }

        return View(person);
  }
```